# What’s the name of this phenomenon occurring when numerically computing the explicit Euler method for this PDE IVP and why does it occur?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, initial-value-problems, eulers-method

I’ve been asked to calculate numerically the solution of this IVP using Euler’s explicit method on Mathlab:

$$u_t-2u_{xx}=0$$
$$u(x,0)=\sin (2\pi x), \quad x\in(0,1)$$
$$u(0,t)=u(1,t)=0, \quad t\in(0,0.05)$$

However, I find the approximation is really bad for $h = 0.04, k = 4 · 10^{-3}$ (here the exact solution is shown in blue and the red dots correspond to the approximated values):

[image]

...then it gets considerably better for a slightly inferior value of $k$: here the same plot is shown for $h = 0.04, k = 4 · 10^{-5}$:

[image]

I’d like to know how is this phenomenon called and why does it occur for this particular IVP. Is there any conditions a numerical method has to meet in order not to present this kind of problems?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Indeed, I edited that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You run afoul of the limited A-stability of the explicit Euler method. If you write the discretized PDE as ODE system $\dot u=F(u)$, then $L=\frac8{h^2}$ is a Lipschitz constant, one can probably reduce that by some percent. A rule-of-thump says that for $Lk>2$ the method is unstable, for $Lk\approx 1$ mostly looking sensible and with $Lk\le 0.5$ starting to give quantitatively correct results.

In your failed experiment you have $L=5000$ and $Lk=20$, thus instability. In the second case you get $Lk=0.2$ which corresponds to sensible results with the errors still visible in the plot.

You can get an even more detailed picture by applying the discrete Fourier-transform to the space discretization. Then the equations for the different frequencies are decoupled from each other. Note that the Euler iteration in space mode provides a continuing source of floating point noise to the amplitude equations in frequency mode. So even amplitudes starting at zero can be perturbed and then amplified by the instability effects.

Comment: Thank you! Is this related to the amplification factor for Euler’s explicit method being $\geq 1$ for $k= 4 · 10^{-5}$?

Comment: It should be smaller than 1, which is the definition for stability. As the second derivatives gives a symmetric matrix in the discretization, all eigenvalues are real and negative, so the condition is $\lambda k\in[-2,0]$. Using the upper bound $|\lambda|\le L$ gives a correspondingly smaller interval for $k$.